# Getting the form field data through javascript is throwing an error (value null)

Tags: javascript, html, forms

```js
function myFunc() {
  console.log("entered");
  document.write('Submitted Data');
  var firstname = document.getElementById("fname").value;
  var lastname = document.getElementById("lname").value;
  document.writeln("Your full name is:" + firstname + lastname);
}
```

```html
<form>
  <label> Firstname </label>
  <input type="text" name="firstname" id="fname" size="15" /> <br> <br>
  <label> Lastname</label>
  <input type="text" name="lastname" id="lname" size="15" /> <br> <br>
  <label>   
    Gender :  
    </label><br>
  <input type="radio" name="male" /> Male <br>
  <input type="radio" name="female" /> Female
  <br>
  <br>
  <input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="myFunc()" />
</form>
```

After clicking on submit, it is not getting first name and showing an error as value null in the console. Can anyone please help? This entire code is saved in one HTML page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because of this line `document.write('Submitted Data');`. `document.write` delete the existing html so in the next line where you are using `document.getELementById` is not able to find the dom element

```js
function myFunc() {
  var firstname = document.getElementById("fname").value;
  var lastname = document.getElementById("lname").value;
  document.writeln("Your full name is:" + firstname + lastname);
}
```

```html
<body bgcolor="Lightskyblue">
  <br>
  <br>
  <form>

    <label> Firstname </label>
    <input type="text" name="firstname" id="fname" size="15" /> <br> <br>
    <label> Lastname</label>
    <input type="text" name="lastname" id="lname" size="15" /> <br> <br>


    <label>   
    Gender :  
    </label><br>
    <input type="radio" name="male" /> Male <br>
    <input type="radio" name="female" /> Female
    <br>
    <br>


    <input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="myFunc()" />
  </form>
</body>
```